# Native GTK# on Windows?

Tags: winapi, gtk, gtk#

How would I compile the latest version of GTK# for Windows without using cygwin?

Any and All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have to have a more recent version, Medsphere provide a [newer version](http://medsphere.org/projects/gtksharp/wiki), and [building instructions](http://medsphere.org/projects/gtksharp/wiki/CompilingGtkSharpOnCygwin) and there is a [load of information here](http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-sharp-list@lists.ximian.com/msg03432.html).

Sounds like some people have built 2.12

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the best place to find the latest official Gtk# release from Novell:
http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/gtk-sharp/

Mike Kestner's blog post about this release and why is it better then previous ones:
http://mkestner.blogspot.com/2009/04/gtk-for-net.html

I tried it and it works perfectly in XP and Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to compile it? [Novell have an installer you could use.](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfmod/project/?gtks-inst4win)

Comment: The problem is that the install is fairly out of date (2.8 vs 2.12 for the current version of GTK#)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need Cygwin to compile C# code?

Comment: Sorry for wrongly voting you down. I removed it. In general you ill need cygwin or mingw or somethin to compile the GTK bit of GTK#.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gtkSharp/GtkSharp/ this repository works on windows, you just need to add the GtkSharp.Dependencies nuget package, and it is compatible with .net 5.0, 3.1 and 4.5 or later

Also, they are planning on supporting gtk4 as you can see here